# Starting JBoss 5.1.0 from Eclipse never registers completion

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss5.x

I've recently run into a problem starting our JBoss 5.1.0 server from Eclipse (Kepler).  Everything usually works fine, and the server starts up. I've recently been tasked with writing a new custom login module, and that's when the problems started. I've been able to get the login module to work properly, and register a proper login, but the server now will not complete startup when the new login module is in use.

I do see the message that the server has started up in the log, but Eclipse won't recognize that it has completed (e.g.: "Started in 2m:10s:000ms"), and eventually times out (I currently have it set to 1000 seconds, and it times out).

Obviously, the first step is to examine the thing that's changed recently, which is the login module. I'm working off of an existing (custom) module, and everything looks very similar to what I've coded up. Unfortunately, I cannot post any sample code, which makes the question more difficult to answer.

-*Edit to add additional information*-

The login module sits in a JAR file, and is using an ehcache instance to cache the user's credentials. The cache instance is accessed by the login module to look up the user's information, and if the cache misses, the cache is using an auto-populator to go grab the user's information, and populate the cache with it. The auto-population logic is encased in an EJB3 container, as a simple EJB service, and the EAR file is dropped into the deploy folder of the server.

Comment: *Unfortunately, I cannot post any sample code, which makes the question more difficult to answer* At least post the technology stack you're using or something that we can use for analysis of this case. For example, I had a similar problem when working with Hibernate, Spring Core and Spring transactions because a service bean had a `@PostConstruct` init method that executed lot fo queries to the database and these queries were not managed by Spring transaction thus the deployment of the app literally stopped the server start. Not sure if this may be your case as well.

Comment: Edited to add information.